# How to prove Mellin transform on $L^2[0,1]$ is unitary?

Tags: complex-analysis, operator-theory, hardy-spaces, mellin-transform

Let $\{Im (s)\lt 0\}=\{s\in \mathbb{C}\mid Im(s)\lt 0\}$, and $H^2(\{Im (s)\lt0\})$ is the [Hardy space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardy_space) on $\{Im (s)\lt 0\}$. I know a classical theorem of Paley and Wiener

> Fourier transform $\mathscr{F}$ is an unitary operator from $L^2(0,\infty)$ to $H^2(\{Im (s)\lt0\})$.

How can I conclude that [Mellin transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mellin_transform) is an unitariy operator from $L^2[0,1]$ to $H^2(\{Re (s)\gt \frac{1}{2}\})$ from the above Paley-Wiener theorem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has nothing to do with complex analysis or Paley-Wiener theorems; it's just the Plancherel theorem plus a change of variables.
Leaving out the $2\pi$s:

Say $\int_0^\infty |f(x)|^2\,dx<\infty$. Let $$g(t)=f(e^{t})e^{t/2}.$$Then $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty|g(t)|^2\,dt=\int_0^\infty|f(x)|^2\,dx$$and $$Mf(s)=\int_0^\infty f(x)x^{-1/2-is}\,dx=\hat g(s).$$So $$||Mf||_{L^2(\Bbb R)}=||g||_{L^2(\Bbb R)}=||f||_{L^2((0,\infty))}.$$

Comment: @David.Thank you for your help. and you can not prove Mellin transform is  a onto map without using Paley-Wiener theorem. However, your answer really show me a hint.

Comment: Sorry, I misread the question. I thought you were asking about the Mellin transform on $L^2((0,\infty))$. You're asking about $L^2([0,1])$. Yes, that has something to do with P-W. I gave an isometry from $L^2((0,\infty))$ onto $L^2(\Bbb R)$. If $f\in L^2([0,1])$ then the function I called $g$ will be in $L^2(-\infty,0))$, and yes, PW then tells us about $\hat g$.